# string element of listA are substrings of listB. How to retrieve and store each string in listB which contains these subsrtings in python?

Tags: python, list

i have following lists

```
listA = ['alpha','beta','gamma'] 
listB = ['alphav1','alphav2','alpha$v3', 'alpha$v4-beta', 
        'alpha-beta','beta$v1', 'betav2', 'beta-alpha', 'beta$v6-get', 'gamma']
```

i wanted to retrieve and store:

```
alpha = ['alphav1','alphav2','alpha$v3', 'alpha$v4-beta']
```

i.e a list named alpha and similarly for beta and gamma

I have to get the this with starting strings only and not any other matching strings! Ex: incase of alpha-beta and alpha$v4-beta fall into alpha and beta-alpha fall into beta.

Note: I have huge listA with 1k+ elements - looking for generic answer with time complexity issue too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

`{i: [j for j in listB if j.startswith(i)] for i in listA}`

which returns:

```
{
    'alpha': [
        'alphav1', 
        'alphav2', 
        'alpha$v3', 
        'alpha$v4-beta', 
        'alpha-beta'
    ], 
    'beta': [
        'beta$v1', 
        'betav2', 
        'beta-alpha', 
        'beta$v6-get'
    ], 
    'gamma': [
        'gamma'
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy job with [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
alpha = filter(lambda s: s.startswith('alpha'), listB)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will make a new list for the items in list b and seperating them based on the first letter of the string.

```
alpha = [x for x in listB if x.startswith('a')]
beta = [x for x in listB if x.startswith('b')]
gamma = [x for x in listB if x.startswith('g')]

print(alpha, beta, gamma, sep='\n')

>>>
['alphav1', 'alphav2', 'alpha$v3', 'alpha$v4-beta', 'alpha-beta']
['beta$v1', 'betav2', 'beta-alpha', 'beta$v6-get']
['gamma']
```

Comment: what if I have list of 1000 elements of list A and 10k+.. in listB?

Comment: Id you want to make the list out of elements in both lists just change 'in listB' to 'in listA + listB'.